# Mongodb spamming log

Tags: logging, mongodb

I found that mongod writes

```
[snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%
```

continuously.

So it one day log now about 2Mb.
What does it mean and how to disable this?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer on my own question, but I found explanation here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/6r0o4yYq2vM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log entries you're seeing are generated when you enable cpu logging in MongoDB, i.e. starting it with the --cpu flag or cpu = true in the config file.  Disabling that option will prevent it from adding those entries to the log file.

You can read about that here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#cpu